# MongoDB not found on OS X 10.10.4

Tags: macos, mongodb

I installed mongoDB on my Mac running OS X 10.10.4.

When I did `which mongo` I got:

```
mongo not found
```

I tried to install mongodb again but I got this:

```
Warning: mongodb-3.0.5 already installed, it's just not linked
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a issue regarding the application path. Installation on Mac OSX doesn't add MongoDB automatically to the system path.

As stated by the official documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/), MongoDB binaries are in the `bin/` directory. One way to fix your issue would to be add the following line to the `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH
```

Replace `<mongodb-install-directory>` with the path to the extracted MongoDB archive.

If all else seems to not work, `cd` into the folder and run `mongod` using

```
./mongod
```

Comment: The *"... already installed, it's just not linked"* error suggests installation was done using Homebrew, in which case commands such as `brew link ...` are easier. (But the question lacks any details, so kudos for the answer.)